# Get a default string from Association if it does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to show a default string if an association does not exist. I am doing like this now:

```
  %td
    - if m.winner.nil?
      = 'No One'
    - else
      = m.winner.country
  %td
    - if m.mom.nil?
      = 'No One'
    - else
      = m.mom.name
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a try with the following code.

```
%td    
 = m.winner.try(:country) || 'No One'
%td
 = m.mom.try(:name) || 'No One'
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways of doing it. One I like the most is to use delegate.

option 1) Add to your m model

```
delegate :name, to: :mom, allow_nil: true
```

and then

```
m.mom.name || "No One"
```

option 2) You can use this also if you are feeling lazy

```
m.mom.name rescue  "No One"
```

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to mention try. It is also a nice option.